# Wordpress bbpress get last 2 posts php

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I'm trying to build a wordpress query to get the last 2 posts from bbpress2.3.2 to display on the home page of the site and I just can't seem to grasp how to do this.

I have been digging about in the DB but still can't find any clues.
Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: If anyone else is looking..

bbpress uses post_type topic. So you can build a get_posts() using 'post_type' => 'topic' as one of the args.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

BBpress store everything in the `wp_posts` table, with different `post_type`.
So if you want to get the last 2 posts, you have the find the right `post_type` (it can be `topic` for topics, or `reply` for replies in the topics). Then you just have to use the Wordpress function `get_posts` :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'reply',
    'numberposts'     => 2,
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

You can change the number of posts you want to get, and the type. With that you should have what you want :)

If you're blocked : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: thanks dude, but I already got there. But maybe this will help another confused soul :-)